# Kotlin type inference failed - type mismatch "Found Array<*?>, Required Array<*>?"

Tags: kotlin

I am encountering an issue with Kotlin's type system. I declared the variable as below at class scope:

```
var planets: ArrayList<Planet>? = null
```

and in the constructor I try to initialize the array but I am encountering a type mismatch error:

```
planets = arrayListOf(earth, mars, saturn, jupiter, uranus, neptune, pluto)
```

error:

```
Required: ArrayList<Planet>?
Found: ArrayList<Planet?>
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

At least one of the planets (`earth, mars, saturn, jupiter, uranus, neptune, pluto`) is of nullable type `Planet?` hence the inferred type of `arrayListOf(earth, ...)` is `ArrayList<Planet?>`.

Since `ArrayList<Planet>` is not contravariant on type `Planet` it cannot be safely to assigned with value `ArrayList<Planet?>`.

To resolve the problem you can:

- make sure all planets are of not nullable type `Planet`
- if the above is not feasible change

  ```
  var planets: ArrayList<Planet>? = null
  ```

  to

  ```
  var planets = arrayListOf<Planet?>()
  ```
- filter out `null` planets and then assign the result collections to `planets`:

  ```
  planets = arrayListOf(*arrayListOf(earth, ...).filterNotNull().toTypedArray())
  ```

Another way to make the compiler happy is to make the `planets` [contravariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) like so:

```
var planets: ArrayList<in Planet>? = null
```

PS. Use [kotlin collection types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html) `List<T>`, `Set<T>` and corresponding `listOf`, `setOf` instead of Java's counterparts whenever possible.

Comment: are you notified somehow about new #kotlin questions? :P

Comment: If you know which planet is nullable, but you're sure it's not, you can simply write `planet!!`

Answer (score 1):

Your planets in the list have type `Planet?`, not `Planet`. Please, check it out.

To fix there are three ways:
1. Change planets type to `Planet`.
2. Change list definition to

```
var planets: ArrayList<Planet?>? = null
```

3. Map existed planets if you sure they are not null

```
planets = ArrayList(listOf(earth, ... ).map { it!! })
// or safer way
planets = ArrayList(listOf(earth, ... ).filterNotNull())
```

Number 2 is the worst one, I prefer number 1, if it is impossible, number 3 as workaround.