# How to convert below line from Java to Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, textview

```
dots = new TextView[layouts.length];
```

Suggested by Kotlin

```
dots = arrayOfNulls<TextView>(layouts.size)
```

and after converting there is error Type Miss match

Required: `Array<TextView>`

Found: `Array<TextView?>`

Comment: did you try - dots = arrayOf(layout.size) or dots = mutableArrayOf(layout.size)?

Comment: Please Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343267/kotlin-type-inference-failed-type-mismatch-found-array-required-array/39343348#39343348) you will solve your problem by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`dots = arrayListOf<TextView>()` that's how you would do it for kotlin for an empty arraylist with non-null values or

`arrayOfNulls<TextView?>(layouts.size)` is for an array of nulls

Comment: Good answer. arrayOfNulls was the bad direction of the OP in my opinio

Comment: The method type parameter is still `arrayOfNulls<TextView>`, it's the returned type which is `Array<TextView?>`.

Comment: @shkschneider When translating to Kotlin, I wouldn't usually make this change immediately. If you already have working code in Java, translate it exactly (using `arrayOfNulls` or `Array` constructor), _then_ you can refactor it.

Comment: That is a very good practice indeed. However, I still find that `new TextView[layouts.length]` translating to NonNull elements would justify to not use `arrayOfNulls` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because an `arrayOfNulls` contains the number of given elements as a "null" object. But `TextView` is only nullable when you write it like `TextView?`. You can filter `dots` if you would like to remove to null values when you have filled it with your data by something like `dots.filterNotNull()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like below:-

```
val dots: Array<TextView?> = arrayOfNulls(layouts.size)
```

Here ? means it can be null.

Before you have your data type as

```
Array<TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's initialized by something like

```
dots = new TextView[layouts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < layouts.length; i++) {
    dots[i] = ... // does something with i
}
```

so afterwards you know it contains no nulls, then it should be typed as `Array<TextView>` and initialized as

```
dots = Array<TextView>(layouts.length) { i -> ... }
```

Otherwise, if it can still contain nulls later when used, change the type to `Array<TextView?>`.