# Why this Koltin code throws error Type mismatch: inferred type is {Comparable<*>? & java.io.Serializable?} but Any was expected

Tags: kotlin, type-mismatch

Here is the code I am facing error:-

fun main(){

```
val nullList = listOf(1, 3, null, "chair", "table", null) 

val nullArrayList = arrayListOf("this", "house", null, 3, 9) 

println("This list without the null values is ${nullList.filterNotNull()}")

println("This array without the null values is ${nullArrayList.filterNotNull()}")
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin type inference failed - type mismatch "Found Array<\*?>, Required Array<\*>?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343267/kotlin-type-inference-failed-type-mismatch-found-array-required-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the question itself:

In your question, you have directly provided the list of elements for both `nullList` and `nullArrayList`. Since you didn't provide any types, it will try to auto-deduce the type for the array ( this is what it means by inferred ). You can see this in the IDE hints :

[image: ide hint image]

You can see that it has inferred the type : `ArrayList<out {Comparable*>? & java.io.Serializale?}>`

Now, when you try to fire : `filterNotNull` it will find out that inferred types do not have that methods available at all.

So, a quick way to bypass this issue to use `Any?` and let the compiler ignore some of the error. This is not recommended in the long run, but should be okay for now.

Solution :

```
fun main(){

    val nullList = listOf<Any?>(1, 3, null, "chair", "table", null)

    val nullArrayList = arrayListOf<Any?>("this", "house", null, 3, 9)

    println("This list without the null values is ${nullList.filterNotNull()}")

    println("This array without the null values is ${nullArrayList.filterNotNull()}")
}
```